# Python игра snake, проблема в звеньях змеи

Tags: python

Решил написать игру змейка. Но проблема возникла чтобы звенья змеи двигались за головой по квадратам. Проблема в том что когда я добавляю 3-й квадрат (он закоменчен 30 строка) то при первом нажатии кнопки движении 2 звена двигаются, а 3ий остается и получается разрыв. При следующих нажатиях движения змеи все отлично змея двигается одним звеном.

проблема в def move строки с 41 по 46.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Main(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Canvas.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.left = False
        self.right = True
        self.up = False
        self.down = False
        self.root.title("Snake")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, bg='#00FF00')
        self.snake=self.canvas.create_oval(20,25, 30, 35 )
        self.canvas.focus_set()
        self.canvas.addtag_above(1, self.snake)
        self.canvas.bind("<Key>", self.onKeyPressed)
        #Сетка
        for i in range(600):
            self.canvas.create_line((14*i, 0),(14*i,480))
        for i in range(480):
           self.canvas.create_line((0 , i*14), (640, i*14))

        self.snake1 = self.canvas.create_rectangle(58, 2, 68, 12, fill='grey', tag='s1') #1-ый Квадрат, голова змеи
        self.snake2 = self.canvas.create_rectangle(44, 2, 54, 12, fill='grey', tag='s2') #2-ой Квадрат
        self.snake3 = self.canvas.create_rectangle(30, 2, 40, 12, fill='grey', tag='s2') #3-ий Квадрат, некоректно работает


        self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


        #b_start = tk.Button(self.canvas, text='Start game',command=self.move)
        #b_start.bind('<Button-1>', command=self.move)
        #b_start.pack(padx='100', pady='100')
#Функция движения змеи
    def move(self):
        #head=self.canvas.find_withtag("s1")
        self.items = [self.snake1, self.snake2, self.snake3]  # список обьектов
        #Этот код позволяет двигаться звеньям одним целым
        i = 0
        while i < len(self.items)-1:
            c1 = self.canvas.coords(self.items[i])
            c2 = self.canvas.coords(self.items[i+1])

            self.canvas.move(self.items[i], c2[0]-c1[0], c2[1]-c1[1])
            i += 1
        if self.left:
            self.canvas.move(self.items, -14, 0)
        if self.right:
            self.canvas.move(self.items, 14, 0)

        if self.up:
            self.canvas.move(self.items, 0, -14)

        if self.down:
            self.canvas.move(self.items, 0, 14)
        print(self.canvas.coords(self.items[i]))


    def onKeyPressed(self, e):

        key = e.keysym

        if key == "a" and not self.right:
            self.left = True
            self.up = False
            self.down = False
            self.move()

        if key == "d" and not self.left:
            self.right = True
            self.up = False
            self.down = False
            self.move()

        if key == "w" and not self.down:
            self.up = True
            self.right = False
            self.left = False
            self.move()

        if key == "s" and not self.up:
            self.down = True
            self.right = False
            self.left = False
            self.move()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app=Main(root)
    root.geometry('600x480+200+200')
    #root.bind("<a>", move)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: 1 - храните квадраты в списке, а не добавляйте для каждого отдельную переменную. 2 - при каждом шаге удаляйте последний квадрат и добавляйте новый в начало с новыми координатами. Либо меняйте коррдинаты последнего квадрата и перемещайте его в начало списка. Все квадраты при каждом шаге перемещать не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за совет идею понял, но не могу реализовать. Не понимаю как двигать список, перепробовал много разного кода все криво с ошибками. Самое лучшее что получилось это исчезновение квадратов=). В коде выше изменил с 40 по 50 строки, как сейчас есть у меня.